# I want to import multiple Thunderbird profile to dovecot for archiving

Tags: dovecot, maildir, thunderbird, mbox

I'm planning to combine my received emails from the last 10-20 years on a server. I've mainly been using Thunderbird on various Windows and Linux computers, so I believe the email formats are mostly in MBox and Maildir.

I recently got a new small computer with Ubuntu Linux and installed the Dovecot mail server. I haven't configured it specifically yet.

I need help with importing the entire folder structure, including all emails, for all email addresses from my Thunderbird profiles into this email server.

As far as I understand, each user typically has a default single IMAP mailbox, under which I assume all the email accounts could be set up as subfolders with their respective directory structures and emails.

However, I'm unsure about how to go about importing my emails from Thunderbird in this way. I'd greatly appreciate any guidance or advice on how to proceed.

So far, my Google searches have yielded suggestions for migrating between two existing email servers or for fetching emails from an IMAP server and permanently storing them in Dovecot. I haven't found any hints on how to configure and execute the import of emails from multiple Thunderbird profiles while preserving the entire folder structure.

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: .. depends on what you want the result to look like? As long as you do not mess with the source directories, just copy the folder structure together and see whether you like it, and redo the operation if not.